# Howto set the resize control of a com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window to the top

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Is it possible to set the resize control of an `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window` not only to the bottom and the right but also to the top and the left?

The window Instance is created as follows:

```
Window window = new Window();  
window.setAutoSize(true);  
window.setTitle(title);  
window.setCanDragReposition(true);  
window.setCanDragResize(true);
```

SmartGWT 6 is in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of the [Isomorphic](https://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/255431-howto-set-the-resize-control-of-a-com-smartgwt-client-widgets-window-to-the-top-and-right?p=255446#post255446) guys, the solution is as simple as follows:

```
// https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/types/EdgeName.html
window.setResizeFrom(EdgeName.L, EdgeName.T);
```